# Connect SQL SEVER DB from network by ODBC

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection, odbc

I need to connect to an SQL server database on the network by ODBC or another way, from the server I can access the database through the ODBC, but from the PC in the network i cannot.

The purpose of that is to view a report for end users  give me solution or ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot about your setup that we'd need to be able to help.  Have you tried any of the steps at the link below besides testing a local connection?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx